# Accessing COM interface from C or C++ in Windows environment

Tags: c++, c, windows, com

I'm relatively new to the Component Object Model specification - I have a simple question:

- How can I access a **COM interface** from a C or C++ application

For instance, accessing Microsoft Excel COM interface to perform basic operations, without user intervention.

Kind regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, you will need to instantiate the object using the COM interface.

This is fairly complicated, more than we can just answer here.

here is a good primer: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/COM/comintro.aspx

Another one: http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/com-tech/activex/tutorials/article.php/c5567

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest looking into ATL if you are using C++, and using C++ if using C. It is very easy to use the #import construct to access COM objects in DLLs or EXEs.

Comment: but that is not really what this person is asking.

Comment: While kenny may not have answered what was asked, he did give an answer to the underlying problem, which is often more valuable.

Comment: Where can I find examples, using ATL with C++ - Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

There is a wonderful article at Microsoft that seems to address this exact question. If you want to stick with straight C++ (i.e. MFC/ATL), you should check out the article as it has loads of sample code:

[How to automate Excel from C++ without using MFC or #import](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/216686/EN-US/)