# Using COM Object in C++

Tags: com

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Accessing COM interface from C or C++ in Windows environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/410005/accessing-com-interface-from-c-or-c-in-windows-environment)

Hi,
I have C# COM obejct (registered by regenv) and i'd like to use it in C++.
How can i do that?
Thanks

Comment: There are a billion references on the web that teach you how to use COM APIs from C++. GIYF.

Answer (score 0):

COM is a very broad topic, with it own terminology, pitfalls, quirks and idioms. It might do no good to throw out a few lines of code that show you how to consume a COM object created via COM Interop here, especially since COM Interop is a magnitude better at hiding those peculiarities from you than using COM in C++ is.

Instead, I'd suggest you read the (infamous) book by Don Box about COM, called "Essential COM". Excerpts of it are available at Google Books, so you can get an idea of it's contents before possibly buying a copy.

Comment: Hmmm.... it's really unnessecary, i have to bring this code to work, one time, no more. few lines can help...